# Old physical shares

Tags: shares

My father bought some shares a long time ago in physical form but he doesn’t remember anything about it such as  where are the docs, how many shares he bought, etc. He only has a client ID.

How can I find out about these shares and how can I transfer these into demat account?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag. Does he remember company name